# External storage Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory, core-data

I am bulding app with ability to record video, audio and images. Every media is stored with CoreData entity and its binary data attribute with *External storage* (option for binary data in Core Data entity). For example one record can have many videos with relation below:

[image]
[image]

So far everything works well but during some performance testing I found that the app is not releasing CoreData object properly or at least predictably (for me).

**First issue** is that when **I delete object from context and save it, it still remains in persistent memory** because I can find it with my own predicated fetch. But for example default fetch for TableView (that code which is generated when you create new project) ignores the deleted object. I delete Record objects e.g. from table view this way:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let object:Record = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Record
        context.delete(object)    
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved")
        } catch {   
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Next issue** is that I am not sure if cascading deletion is performed in this moment...

Which points me to **third and last issue** - **the binary data files remain in app memory** (checked with downloading App Container via Xcode). This major issue causes the app uncontrollably "expands".

I was believing that *External storage* solves this issue automatically. Even when I manually nil the variable which holds the binary data, real file still remains in persistent memory.

So questions may sound like this:

**1. When Core Data releases object really permanently from persistent memory?**

**2. When is External binary data deleted from persistent memory?**

Thanks all of you for your help!

**UPDATE #1:**

So according to [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1) there are held strong references to managed objects. Chapter *Breaking Strong References Between Objects* describes it well. Unfortunately nothing of suggested there helped me with the issue described above.

**UPDATE #2:**

Issue with files solved, it was a bug in my code because I forgot to clear temporary folders and destinations...

J.